# Can threads create sub-threads in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am familiar with the syntax for creating threads in python.

```python
from threading import Thread
from queue import Queue

task_queue = Queue(maxsize=0)    

num_threads=10
for i in range(num_threads):
    thread = Thread(target=work, args=(task_queue,))
    thread.start()

task_queue.join()
```

My question is weather it is ok to open up new threads 'inside' other threads like so:

```python
def work(task_queue):
    task = task_queue.get()

    subtasks = task.get_sub_tasks()

    for subtask in subtasks:
        thread = Thread(target=sub_work, args(subtask,))
        thread.start()
```

So

1. Is this structure ok? or is it to messy to do it this way?
2. If this is ok, are the sub-thread processes subordinated to the thread that generated it, or do they become children of the parent python process? If the thread that created the sub-thread "dies" with an error, what happens to the sub-thread?

I realize python threads are subject to the interpreter global lock, but my application involves access to a server, so the multi threading is to avoid serialized connections which would take too long.

Comment: Yes, spawning threads from within another thread is OK. Just remember that there exists a _main_ Python thread, that governs the others.

Comment: I don't see why spawning new threads from a thread would be an issue, actually the first thread you spawn is already a sub thread of the main thread. Now I think you are confusing threads and processes given your 2nd question, every thread is subordinated to the process that spawns them, and though for the OS it does not really matter which thread "owns" which, on a design perspective, it is always better to have subthreads owned by the thread which started them

Comment: @asettouf The second question comes from observing `htop` with tree view. The threads are all branches of the python script. And I believe this affects what threads get killed if i kill another. (I've just edited to clarify what I mean)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So regarding your questions:

- Q1: It is not a problem to start "subthreads" from a thread
- Q2: It is actually an interesting question, my instinct would say "no", but getting a proof sounds better to me

So I created a quick test as below (I would use a gist but I can't access such things from where I am):

```
from threading import Thread
import time

def sub_worker(id):
    print("SubWorker started from thread", id)
    while True:
        print("Subworking...")
        time.sleep(5)
def worker(id):
    print("Worker started from thread", id)
    count = 1
    while count < 5:
        print("Working...")
        tmp_thread = Thread(target=sub_worker, args=[count])
        tmp_thread.start()
        count +=1
        time.sleep(1)
    raise EnvironmentError("Tired of working")

main = Thread(target=worker, args=[0])

main.start()
```

Which gives us the output (as expected an error in the parent thread does not stop the "children"):

```
Worker started from thread 0
Working...
SubWorker started from thread 1
Subworking...
Working...
SubWorker started from thread 2
Subworking...
Working...
SubWorker started from thread 3
Subworking...
Working...
SubWorker started from thread 4
Subworking...
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Temp\tt\Tools\Anaconda3.4.3.1\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Temp\tt\Tools\Anaconda3.4.3.1\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:/Temp/tt/Tools/PyCharmWorkspace/xml_parse/test.py", line 18, in worker
    raise EnvironmentError("Tired of working")
OSError: Tired of working

Subworking...
Subworking...
Subworking...
Subworking...
Subworking...
Subworking...
Subworking...
```

I think that htop shows this hierarchy might be due to the fact that [threads are treated as processes](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=370047&seqNum=3) by the Linux kernel. And since a call to fork is made it can shows this hierarchy. With the concept of threads, I do not believe that a hierarchy makes so much sense as each of them will share the same resources (memory, file descriptors ...etc)